# Spring Boot Thymeleaf SpelEvaluationException EL1007E when submitting a form

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to handle a form submission with `thymeleaf` in my spring-boot application, i integrated
[this example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) which worked fine on my app. I'm trying to change it a little bit, but this is what i'm getting as an **exception**:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'recruiter' cannot be found on null
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213) ~[spring-expression-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]

...
```

This is the object i'm trying to handle with `thymeleaf`

```java
public class FormRec {

private String recruiter;
public String getRecruiter() {
    return recruiter;
}
public void setRecruiter(String recruiter) {
    this.recruiter = recruiter;
}


}
```

This is my `Controller`

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.service.minimicroservice.objects.FormRec;

@Controller
public class MyController {




      @GetMapping("/form")
      public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("recForm", new FormRec());
        return "form";
      }

      @PostMapping("/form")
      public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute FormRec rec) {
        return "result";
      }


}
```

`result.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'Recruiter: ' + ${rec.recruiter}" />
    <a href="/form">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

part of the `form.html`

```html
<body>

                    <form action="#" th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${recForm}" method="post">
                        <div class="form-row m-b-55">
                            <div class="name">Recruiter<br> Name</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <div class="row row-space">
                                    <div class="col-2">
                                        <div class="input-group-desc">
                                            <input class="input--style-5" type="text" name="first_name" th:field="*{recruiter}">
                                            <label class="label--desc">Full Name</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
...
```

In order to refer to a `FormRec` Object i use `recForm` as `th:object` in the `form.html` and `rec` to refer to it in the `result.html`.

Note: I pass a value to the `th:field="*{recruiter}"` input text when i submit the form (**is not null**)

Comment: You are calling `rec.recruiter` in `result.html`, but do you pass the `rec` object to that html page?

Comment: i think it get's handled by it self when you are passing a **@ModelAttribute** at the @PostMapping method

Comment: check out the example in the introduction part

Comment: Yeah sorry, had to take a better look at it in the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name the ModelAttribute `rec` that the data gets bound to. So in your controller method do this (notice the `name = "rec"`):

```
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute(name = "rec") FormRec rec) {
...
}
```

It should work.

**Additional explanation:**

I've had a closer look at why that happens and it's because Spring's `ModelAttribute` annotation by default infers from the **name of the type** and not the name of the parameter (the example link you provided says it's method parameter name, but it seems to be wrong).

So in this case Spring sends `formRec` (notice the camelCase, which it expects when the class name is called `FormRec`) to the `result.html` and not `rec` as you would expect.

If my explanation doesn't really make sense, then this is the Spring documentation on **`ModelAttribute`**:

> The default model attribute name is inferred from the declared attribute type (i.e. the method parameter type or method return type), based on the non-qualified class name: e.g. "orderAddress" for class "mypackage.OrderAddress", or "orderAddressList" for "List".

Comment: It worked thanks! Although the spring-boot example did not include this...

Comment: You're right. I added additional explanation on this. It seems that the one sentence about the greeting parameter name inference in the Spring example is either outdated or wrong.